# Name servers not resolved leading to DNS lookup failure

Tags: domain-name-system, hosting, nameserver, domain-registrar

So it's difficult to give a short title to this but I'll go over a brief back story...
So I have the domain [repo-itechy21.tk](http://repo-itechy21.tk) and have hosting with 000webhost. (ew) it's been a good 30 hours and my domain registrar is saying that it's not them, and 000webhost is saying it's not them...
So who is causing this issue
(I have modified .htacsess and contents are below)

```
# Do not remove this line, otherwise mod_rewrite rules will stop working
RewriteBase /
Options -Indexes
```

Comment: Maybe put this into a structured sentence of some kind rather than implying a question in the tile and then putting a rambling statement in the body.

Comment: @joeqwerty Dad mode, _ACTIVATE!_

Answer (score 3):

```
dig +trace soa repo-itechy21.tk

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> +trace soa repo-itechy21.tk
;; global options: +cmd
.           2955    IN  NS  c.root-servers.net.
.           2955    IN  NS  j.root-servers.net.
.           2955    IN  NS  l.root-servers.net.
.           2955    IN  NS  g.root-servers.net.
.           2955    IN  NS  e.root-servers.net.
.           2955    IN  NS  f.root-servers.net.
.           2955    IN  NS  a.root-servers.net.
.           2955    IN  NS  k.root-servers.net.
.           2955    IN  NS  h.root-servers.net.
.           2955    IN  NS  m.root-servers.net.
.           2955    IN  NS  b.root-servers.net.
.           2955    IN  NS  i.root-servers.net.
.           2955    IN  NS  d.root-servers.net.
;; Received 228 bytes from 172.20.10.1#53(172.20.10.1) in 47 ms

tk.         172800  IN  NS  d.ns.tk.
tk.         172800  IN  NS  c.ns.tk.
tk.         172800  IN  NS  b.ns.tk.
tk.         172800  IN  NS  a.ns.tk.
;; Received 277 bytes from 192.58.128.30#53(192.58.128.30) in 49 ms

repo-itechy21.tk.   300 IN  NS  ns01.000webhost.com.
repo-itechy21.tk.   300 IN  NS  ns02.000webhost.com.
;; Received 86 bytes from 194.0.38.1#53(194.0.38.1) in 199 ms

;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Looks like the name servers for 000webhost.com aren't coughing up any records for your domain. Looks like it's them.

Comment: Thanks very much for this it's there really bad support that's bugging me DX

Comment: Just waiting for their reply using the code you posted I hope they solve it...

Comment: nope just got a reply saying contact the domain registrar... DX I hope this doesn't go in a loop

Comment: @itechy21 Get a different DNS host. Route53 from Amazon is just dollars per month depending on how many DNS requests you get. Go to your registrar, change the nameservers that your domain points to, and get off of 000webhost.com. If you want free, check out afraid.org but not before you read this: http://serverfault.com/questions/655349/somebody-created-subdomain-without-my-knowledge-how/655350#655350

Comment: I don't like the look of that :o having miscellaneous sub domains put up on my domain.... And then redirecting to the sub domain... I may go back to my friends web host for £3 a month